# How to exclude some string with grep and awk cmd?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is there any way to exclude some string with regEx format by using grep and awk cmd.?
I have a grep output as below,

```
             msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=ServiceLayer->Application[2015-12-17 12:13:57.281][000000012][00052] [SDK_SSF][Trace]
             msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=ServiceLayer->Application[2015-12-17 12:13:57.461][000000012][00052] [SDK_SSF][Trace]
             msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=Application->ServiceLayer[2015-12-17 12:13:57.461][000000001][00052] [SDK_CS][Trace]
```

I need a output which does not contain date and timeStamp, well i used direct 'awk $2' But its outputting the date also since date is not in separate column.

any other way to get the output as below ?

```
             msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=ServiceLayer->Application[000000012][00052] [SDK_SSF][Trace]
             msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=ServiceLayer->Application[000000012][00052] [SDK_SSF][Trace]
             msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=Application->ServiceLayer[000000001][00052] [SDK_CS][Trace]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use sed to remove the first brackets.

```
sed 's/\[[^\[]*\]//' file
```

or

```
sed 's/\[[0-9.: -]*\]//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cut -d'[' -f1,3,4,5,6
         msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=ServiceLayer->Application[2015-12-17 12:13:57.281][000000012][00052] [SDK_SSF][Trace]
         msgBody               |flowid=9984|level=0|flow=ServiceLayer->Application[000000012][00052] [SDK_SSF][Trace]
```

Comment: Check `--compliment` option: `cut -d'[' -f2 --compliment`